# How to create database table (or storage bucket) per user on Firebase & Angular 6?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angular5

This is kinda newbie question.

I'm building a web app with user authentication system on Firebase.

This app features an upload image section, html5 canvas. Users should be able to save what they draw on HTML5 canvas as private data which no other users can see.
So I have to dynamically create user data table or storage bucket when a user registers. 
How can I do this using Firebase and Angular?

Please send me any github source example or leave a reply.
Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Take a loot at this example. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md. As you can see you can use AngularFire2 do abstract your Firebase needs. After upload you just need to edit the rules on Firebase Storage and there you go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to apply [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) to the firebase realtime database in order to only allow particular users read/write permissions to some path in the data tree.

E.g.

```
{ "rules": {
    "userdata": {
        "$uid": {
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
    }
}
```

Here we are allowing user read/write access to a path in the data tree

> /userdata/{theUsersId}

. So a user with uid=abcdefg could read/write to

> /userdata/abcdefg

The rules above do not validate the data within that path, so you could put any JSON object there. [Note a maximum depth of 32 is in force](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)

You could then create the object on the client side when the user is created. Here an example using [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/144) which I quite recommend.

```
class MyClass
    constructor(af: AngularFire) {}

    createUser(userDetails: UserInterface, userData:any){
        return this.af.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userDetails.email, userDetails.password)
            .then(firebaseUser=>{
                userDetails.uid = firebaseUser.uid;
                //get firebase ref
                const userDataRef = this.af.database.object('/userdata/${userDetails.uid}');
                return userDataRef.set(userData);
            })
   }
}
```

If you want more complicated security rules, I find the JSON structure to be a bit unwieldy to you might want to look at how [bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt) works.

If you interest in doing similar with firebase storage(buckets) I suggest reading [this article](https://medium.com/@fpastorelima/per-user-storage-limit-validation-with-firebase-19ab3341492d) as it includes an example of how to write user based storage rules.